# Change screen resolution of xubuntu-14.04.3 using VirtualBox running on Windows 10

Tags: xubuntu, virtualbox, display, display-resolution, windows-10

I want to run a development environment of Ubuntu on my Windows 10 machine, since I'm just using it for coding I thought I'd just download xubuntu since I only really need a lightweight OS to run on a virtual machine.

I've got xubuntu running on my VirtualBox but the screen resolution is locked at 640x480 without any options to change it to be a higher resolution.  I can't handle coding on such a tiny resolution, is there anyway I can change the resolution a more reasonable resolution?

My xubuntu version is: xubunut-14.04.3
Host machine:  Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install the virtualbox guest additions. They change the resolution, enable drag and drop, and some more.

You can read it here:

[How do I install Guest Additions in a VirtualBox VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm)

Now, the resolution will change according to your virtualbox window.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, saves me from running through tons of other steps to finding the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use Guest box additions.

more info on how to do this :

`http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm`

Thanks